# Using a class template's static constexpr as the template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a base class that contains a buffer with a templated size. I then create subclasses with specific sizes. The sizes should all be multiples of the same number. I thought I'd make that number a constexpr in the base class, but the compiler won't accept the constexpr as a template parameter. Here's some example code:

```
template<int buf_size> class A
{
    public:
        static constexpr int basic_size = 256;
    protected:
        int buf[buf_size];
};

class B : A<2 * A::basic_size>
{
    public:
        void other_stuff();
};
```

But the compiler tells me that "template argument 1 is invalid". I tried adding <> after A, but it didn't help:

```
class B : A<2 * A<>::basic_size>   //Same error
```

It looks like I have to provide an actual number as the template parameter:

```
class B : A<2 * A<0>::basic_size>  //Works!
```

That's pretty ugly, though. I'm new to C++. Is there a better way to do this? I'm writing code for a microcontroller, so I need buffers to be statically allocated at compile time -- hence the templates.

Comment: Why make this a `static constexpr` variable? Just make it `constexpr` at namespace-scope instead of class-scope.

Comment: I was trying to keep as much information in the class itself as possible, but maybe that's the wrong thing to do here. I thought that defining constants in a broader scope was more of a C thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The sizes should all be multiples of the same number.

If that's the intent, you are not using the number correctly in the posted code. I suggest:

```
template<unsigned int Multiplier=1> class A
{
    public:
        static constexpr int basic_size = 256;
    protected:
        int buf[buf_size*Multiplier];
};

class B : A<2>
{
    public:
        void other_stuff();
};
```